# Adapting CSS slide out panel example

Tags: css

I am trying to adapt an excellent slideout panel example from [here](http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/).

adapted code is [here](http://codepen.io/jetpacmonkey/pen/ktIJz)

I like to have different icons for hide/expanded state (something like > when hidden, < when expanded). Is it possible by changing the above code. Ultimately I may use icons from [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#)

Thanks.

### EDIT:

To be clear on the changes from the original version, the code I plan to use doesn't use the same markup. This is to avoid hindering the history. Please use the version http://codepen.io/jetpacmonkey/pen/ktIJz

```
<header class="main-header">
    <label for="main-nav-check" class="toggle-menu">
      ☰
    </label>

    <h1>cssPanelMenu</h1>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using pseudo elements (IE8+). Replace the icon with a `span` with class `.icon` and then hook up a `:before` style to show the content based on whether the checkbox is checked.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/Tyriar/pen/nJGfj)

**HTML**

```
<label for="main-nav-check" class="toggle-menu">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-nav-check:checked ~ .page-wrap .icon:before {
  content:"<";
}

#main-nav-check ~ .page-wrap .icon:before {
  content:">";
}
```

Comment: Will accept once it allows me. based on your qn, a new challenge :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732211/slide-out-panel-with-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
<a href="#main-nav" class="open-menu">
  ☰
</a>
<a href="#" class="close-menu">
  ☰
</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#main-nav" class="open-menu">
  >
</a>
<a href="#" class="close-menu">
  <
</a>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nImtd

Comment: well, the adapted code doesn't use the same. I will edit the qn to be clear on this.