# Slide out panel with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap, and trying to do something similar [here](http://codepen.io/Tyriar/pen/nJGfj) (a slide out panel).
I have seen the `nav-collapse` effect which is quite similar except it drops down from above and only appears below a certain screen size. Hope the existing code may be able to use the effect as in

http://codepen.io/Tyriar/pen/nJGfj

is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I've previously used Javascript based plugin called SnapJS:
https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/

There are some useful implementation demos here:
http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html

Answer (score 6):

This looks pretty much like what you need, and it's compatible with Bootstrap 3.0:
https://github.com/stevepeak/bump

This is a pretty old question, but for the sake of google searches, I thought it might be good.

Comment: link is dead now